# Merging 7 Satellite Images into 1 Image

Tags: arcgis-desktop, qgis-3, envi

I want to join 7 images [that is in .tiff] and merge and than subset the area using shapefile. But i am not able to merge it. I have loaded the images as raster layer and than merge it Using Qgis and not getting desired result.
This is the sample image when loaded as a raster layer.
[image]

Adter I load all the iamges it looks like this.
[image]

So which software which method should i used?

I am getting this result and the color is blown gone out.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Please decide which of the GIS products mentioned you want to ask about.  By asking about more than one you are effectively asking multiple questions which goes against the [Tour]. You should then describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: After merging the image color is gone as you can see so i am stuck there how to perform merge image successful without lossing the color.
I have done that i qgis i have mentioned that above.

Comment: have you tried to use Histogramme tools for rasters? "Extending the histogram"
That solved my prob

Comment: @zlikotp Can you share link or something for that i don't know that to do that.

Comment: ok so go to View -> Tool bar -> and check Raster. You'll see several histogram buttons. In my case, after merged 2 orthophotos, the results were too light. Using this button has solve the problem. let me know !

Comment: Thxs Zlikotp My problem is solved. You were a life-savier for me :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so go to View -> Tool bar -> and check Raster. You'll see several histogram buttons. In my case, after merged 2 orthophotos, the results were too light. Using this button has solve the problem. let me know ! –